# better way to create dynamic buttons in asp .net / c# that can access dynamic textboxes and remember their former values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, session-variables

Here's the thing, I now have a working prototype of what I want and it seems to work perfectly for what I want to do.  With that said, this cannot POSSIBLY be the best way to do it.  And by best I mean both in terms of program simplicity but also HOW i actually coded it.  Anyways first a description of what the page should do:

1) the page contains a textbox (Textbox1), a placeholder (Placeholder1), and a button (Button1)

the code for this is simple:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

<hr />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<hr />
```

2) the user can put a number into the textbox (lets say 99) and click the button.  the placeholder will then be filled with 99 textboxes with a "save" button next to each one
3)the user can edit any textbox and click save next to it and the function that is then called by the button click event needs to be able to have access to A) the textboxes current value, B) the textboxes old value, C) any amount of meta data

here is my current working solution:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createStuff(false);

    }

    void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Response.Write(btn.ID + "Clicked" + "<br />");
        Response.Write("Metadata: " + Session[btn.ID + "a"] + "<br />");
        Response.Write("Old text: " + Session[btn.ID + "b"] + "<br />");

        TextBox txtBlah = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("txt"+btn.ID);
        Response.Write("New text: " + txtBlah.Text + "<br />");

        Session[btn.ID + "b"] = txtBlah.Text;

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["num"] = TextBox1.Text;
        createStuff(true);
    }

    private void createStuff(bool btnClick)
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();

        int numBtn = Convert.ToInt32(Session["num"]);

        for (int i = 0; i < numBtn; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtTemp = new TextBox();
            txtTemp.Text = "old" + i;
            txtTemp.ID = "txt" + "btn" + i;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtTemp);

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "btn" + i;
            btn.ID = "btn" + i;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(test);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);

            Session[btn.ID + "a"] = "meta" + i;

            if (btnClick)
            {
            Session[btn.ID + "b"] = txtTemp.Text;
            }

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }


    }
```

I think this is actually pretty decent and I am very happy with it. But, I know there have to be some improvements i can make since some of the tutorials on how the ASP postback system and object model or whatever its called are even now confusing me some.

any help or even just ideas are helpful thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only major improvement i can see is: use a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), put the `TextBox` and `Button` inside, add properties (like OldValue/NewValue, stored in ViewState/TextBox) and add these UserControls to the `PlaceHolder` after you've created instances by using [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.loadcontrol.aspx).

The "MetaData" should also be stored as property in the UserControl. You should use Events to communicate between the UserControl and Page(f.e. `TextSaved`).

You can store the number of created controls in ViewState instead of the Session. That's the only thing you need to store in the Page. Append the index of the UserControl to it's ID.

---

General advantages of a Web User Control:

The biggest advantage of the Web User controls is that they can be created as a site template and used through out the site. For example they can be made to contain the Menu/Link structure of a site and can be used at all the other aspx pages.

This means the following :

- If the website introduces a new site-wide link within the current layout/structure, it is enough if we put it on the user control once. All pages will be updated once if the web user control is used in them.
- If there is any link to be corrected, it can be done once at the server side.
- The .ascx files can either be used as a simple alternative to the plain HTML or they can also be used to respond to events: This means even custom code can be created against them and put in the code behind files.
- http://www.dotnet-guide.com/usercontrol5.html

UserControls encapsulate complexity what is always good to increase

- [Reusability](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/usercontrol6.html)
- Readability
- Maintainability
- Extensibility

... and to reduce the possibility of errors

Read [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540741/284240) for more examples.

Comment: is there any way u could give me some small code examples of what ur talking about?

Comment: @chilleo: It's diffifult to minimize a helpful code sample, apart fom that my main language is VB.NET. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/Page_UserControl.aspx) you'll find a lot of helpful stuff regarding UserControl<->Page communication. You should have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw.aspx) to see how to create UserControls and add them to the page. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5266670/284240) is an answer that is related to the recreation of the contol in postbacks.

Comment: hey tim i think i have read enough tutorials to understand most of what u recommended but if you wouldnt mind could you say *why* i should do it these ways like why it would be an *improvement* like as far as using viewstate I guess just to do that because that way the information is emptied when they leave the page? and so your saying to use the textbox viewstates to save the old and new values so that when they no longer exist that information is also freed up from memory? does that sound right?

Comment: @chilleo: Edited my answer to provide some advantages of a UserControl. The ViewState is only a minor improvement, you can keep your session approach if you want. I would store the `OldValue` also in ViewState(actually a property in the UserControl that returns/sets a ViewState value) since you need to store it somewhere(the user can overwrite the old value in the TextBox).

Answer (score 0):

ok i dunno if this is the right place for me to post back my newest code but i guess it would count as an "answer".  also I want to say thank you so much for your answers they have been incredibly helpful. a little cryptic but fifty pages of tutorials or so later and yes your recomendations were fantastic so thank you and bravo.  anyways heres my newest one that works perfectly with what I think are your recomended additions.  if you want to take a peak and see if youd still do anything a little different or maybe in an easier way please feel free to let me know

first my user control "MyControl"

ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="DBtest.MyControl" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
```

ascx.cs:

```
    //private String _oldText;
    private String _metaData;

    public String OldText
    {
        get
        {
            //return _oldText;
            return (String)ViewState["OldText"];
        }
        set
        {
            //_oldText = value;
            ViewState["OldText"] = value;
        }
    }

    public String MetaData
    {
        get
        {
            return _metaData;
        }
        set
        {
            _metaData = value;
        }
    }

    public String NewText
    {
        get
        {
            return TextBox1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            TextBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("My ID: " + this.ID + "<br />");
        Response.Write("My Metadata: " + _metaData + "<br />");
        Response.Write("My Old Text: " + ViewState["OldText"] + "<br />");
        Response.Write("My New Text: " + TextBox1.Text + "<br />");

        ViewState["OldText"] = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

then my page, aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TESTdynamicButton3.aspx.cs" Inherits="DBtest.TESTdynamicButton3" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Spinner" Src="MyControl.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <hr />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <hr />

</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createStuff(false);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["num"] = TextBox1.Text;
        createStuff(true);
    }

    private void createStuff(bool btnClick)
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        int numBtn = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["num"]);

        for (int i = 0; i < numBtn; i++)
        {
            MyControl temp2 = LoadControl("MyControl.ascx") as MyControl;
            temp2.ID = "uc" + i;
            temp2.MetaData = "meta" + i;
            //not sure why this DOES work, i would think it is overwritten each page load >.<
            temp2.OldText = "old" + i;

            if (btnClick)
            {
                temp2.NewText = "old" + i;
                //not sure why this doesnt work below this line
                //temp2.OldText = "old" + i;
            }

            //also not sure why this won't work
            //temp2.OldText = temp2.NewText;

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(temp2);
        }
    }
```

and i also have a couple contents where im not sure it makes perfect sense why or do or dont use these lines to get the "old text" viewstate to populate properly initially. i would have thought i need to have that buttonclick check and only set the viewstate that first time to get it to work. also im not sure i understand why when i tried moving the createStuff() function to OnInit or the pre init functions overridden it wouldnt work..

thanks!

Leo